# Can I update a global array using a for-in loop, and use the updated array outside of the loop ? (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, scope, for-in-loop

I am currently fetching ImageUrls from Firestore, and accessing them using a for-in loop. Within the for-in loop, I append to a global array using .append(). However, when I call the array outside of the for-in loop, it is empty. I read the response to this post '[IOS Swift value of an Integer is not being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811500/ios-swift-value-of-an-integer-is-not-being-saved)' which was helpful in understanding that my global array is empty because the for-in loop is being executed after I call my array, and how to overcome this problem when using a closure - but how can I achieve the same result when using a for-in loop ? Any direct help or links to helpful articles/videos/posts will be much appreciated.

I know there are similar posts to this, but I went through them and there was only the one I referenced above referring to this problem in swift, so I read that but still struggling. Will attach code below:

// global array of strings which I want to append to:

```
var tuwoImageUrls = [String]()

internal var tuwos: [Tuwo]? {
    didSet {
        self.pickerView.pickerView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

// function fetching documents ('tuwos') from firestore:

```
func fetchTuwos(completion handler: @escaping ([Tuwo]?, Error?) -> ()) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return handler(nil, nil)
    }

    Firestore.firestore()
        .collection("tuwos").document(uid).collection("tuwos")
        .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            handler(querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap({
                Tuwo(dictionary: $0.data())
            }), error)
        }
}
```

// calling function, accessing documents to append ImageUrl to global array ('tuwoImageUrls') using for-in loop:

```
    fetchTuwos { [weak self] (tuwos, error) in
        self?.tuwos = tuwos

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            for tuwo in self!.tuwos! {
                let tuwoImageUrl = "\(tuwo.profileImageUrl)"
                self!.tuwoImageUrls.append("\(tuwoImageUrl)")
                self!.pickerView.pickerView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
```

// calling a print statement of the array outside of the scope of fetchTuwos returns an empty array

```
    print("The Urls:" , tuwoImageUrls)
```

// my 'Tuwo' struct

```
struct Tuwo {
let name, profileImageUrl, uid: String

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
    self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
}}
```

Comment: Just put the line `print("The Urls:" , tuwoImageUrls)` **into** the closure after the `for` loop. By the way it's unnecessarily expensive to reload the picker view in each iteration of the loop. And why do you create a string from a string with `"\(tuwo.profileImageUrl)"` and once again another new string with `"\(tuwoImageUrl)"`?? Both String Interpolations are pointless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this solution helps

```
fetchTuwos { [weak self] (tuwos, error) in
    self?.tuwos = tuwos
    self?.tuwoImageUrls = tuwos?.map { "\($0.profileImageUrl)" } ?? []

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.pickerView.pickerView.reloadData()
    }
    print("\(tuwoImageUrls)")

}
```

Comment: Hi Rita, thank you for your response ! trying the code now but I am getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to closure result type '[String]"

any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Sure thing @RitaLytvynenko I have updated my post to include my Tuwo struct at the bottom

Comment: I checked my code in playground and update my answer. But I'm not sure where you could get "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to closure result type '[String]" error. Here `self?.tuwoImageUrls = tuwos?.map { "\($0.profileImageUrl)" } ?? []` ?

Comment: Thanks again Rita, I've tried your code but if I use print("Image Urls outside of closure:", tuwoImageUrls) outside of the closure I'm still getting an empty array back. I've tried to play around with the code a bit but to no avail. Both fetchTuwos() and my print statement are being called in viewDidLoad() {} and if I call print("tuwoImageUrls in closure:", tuwoImageUrls) inside fetchTuwos, it executes on my console before the print statement outside of the closure, any idea ?

Comment: You load your tuwos and tuwoImageUrls asynchronously, so for getting updated data you should print your values after closure execute.

Comment: Thanks Rita, v helpful and have figured it out thanks to your response !